# Write a function bracket by len that takes a word as an input argument and returns the word bracketed to indicate its length

Tags: c

I am facing issues in the code I need to do the following

if word length > 10  add word in between /++/

if word length > 4  add word in between **

if word length > 0 add word in between <<>>

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char *bracket_by_len(char *,const char*, int n);
int main(void){
    
  char str[20];
  char temp[40];
  printf("Enter a string : ");
  scanf("%[^\n]%*c ",str);

 bracket_by_len(temp,str, 20);
  int i = 0;
  printf("%s",temp);

  return (0);
}

char *bracket_by_len(char *temp,const char* arr, int n){
    char res[40];
    int i = 0;
    if(strlen(arr) > 10){
        res[0] = '/';
        res[1] = '+';
        while(arr[i++] !='\0'){
            res[2 + i] = arr[i];
        }
        res[2 + i] = '+';
        res[2+ (i+1)] = '/';

    }
    if(strlen(arr) > 4){
        res[0] = '*';
       
        while(arr[i++] !='\0'){
            res[1 + i] = arr[i];
        }
        res[1 + i] = '*';
        
        
    }
    if(strlen(arr) > 0){
        res[0] = '<';
        res[1] = '<';
        while(arr[i++] !='\0'){
            res[2 + i] = arr[i];
        }
        res[2 + i] = '>';
        res[2+ (i+1)] = '>';

    }
    strncpy(temp,res, 24);
    *temp = '\0';
    return res;


}
```

The output should be
Call: bracket_by_len(tmp, "insufficiently, 20")
output: /+insufficiently+/

But in my program it is not  showing  anything in output after entering string

Comment: `strlen(res)` did you meant `strlen(arr)`?

Comment: Your function `bracket_by_len` return a pointer to the first element of the ***local*** array `res`. Being a local variable, the life-time of `res` ends when the function returns, and any pointer to it will become invalid. The natural solution is to add a pair of extra arguments to the `bracket_by_len` function, which is a pointer to an array to receive the result, and the size of that array (to avoid writing out of bounds).

Comment: Also note that the `strcpy` and `strncpy` (and most other related functions) have the *destination* as the first argument. And there's a corner-case where `strncpy` will not add the ending null-terminator to the destination.

Answer (score 0):

There're several bug in your code. Let's see one by one.

---

**`scanf("%[^\n]%*c ",str)`**

here you've given an additional space at the end.

---

**`bracket_by_len(temp,str, 20)`**

what does this `20` mean? It's the maximum size of input string?

If it is, then you can define that globally so that you can access it from anywhere.

After sending this parameter in the method, you're not using it anywhere.

---

**`while(arr[i++] !='\0')`**

This is not correct. You're increasing value of `i` right after checking the previous one is null or not.

Hence within the loop, your code will copy from second character, not the first one.

Rather you can run like following:

```
while(arr[i] !='\0')
{
    ... = ar[i++];
}
```

Or

```
while(arr[i] !='\0')
{
    ... = ar[i];
    i++;
}
```

Here's a helpful resource to learn more about while loop.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_while_loop.htm

---

The way you're handling the index of the `res` array, it's not a very good idea.
Rather you can simply take an `int` variable by which you'll be able to handle the index.

For example:

```
int resLen = 0;
res[len++] = ..;
```

---

You're copying the result string in another character array. And you're using this array in the main method.

So you can make the `bracket_by_len` **void** as you're not using the return value.

---

Within the `bracket_by_len` method, you're using only `if` to check all the condition.

Consider the string "`abcdefghijk`". Every condition you'll be true for this string. So according to you're code, result will be a wrong value.

So try using `if else` condition.

Here's a helpful resource to learn more about if else condition.

https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-if-else-statement

Here's the overall sample code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 40

char *bracket_by_len(char *,char*);

int main(void)
{
    char str[MAX_LENGTH];
    char temp[MAX_LENGTH];

    printf("Enter a string : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c",str);

    bracket_by_len(temp,str);
    printf("%s",temp);

    return (0);
}

char *bracket_by_len(char *temp, char* arr)
{
    char res[MAX_LENGTH];
    int resultStringLen = 0;
    int mainStringLen = strlen(arr);
    int ind = 0;

    if(mainStringLen > 10)
    {
        res[resultStringLen++] = '/';
        res[resultStringLen++] = '+';
        while(arr[ind] !='\0')
        {
            res[resultStringLen++] = arr[ind++];
        }
        res[resultStringLen++] = '+';
        res[resultStringLen++] = '/';
    }
    else if(mainStringLen > 4)
    {
        res[resultStringLen++] = '*';

        while(arr[ind] !='\0')
        {
            res[resultStringLen++] = arr[ind++];
        }
        res[resultStringLen++] = '*';
    }
    else if(mainStringLen > 0)
    {
        res[resultStringLen++] = '<';
        res[resultStringLen++] = '<';
        while(arr[ind] !='\0')
        {
            res[resultStringLen++] = arr[ind++];
        }
        res[resultStringLen++] = '>';
        res[resultStringLen++] = '>';
    }
    res[resultStringLen] = '\0';
    strncpy(temp,res, 24);
}
```

**Note**: There're several ways you might follow to do the same task. I didn't mention any alternative way cause I thought it would be better to know the current mistakes, then resolve those, then make it work.